# How to use SQL alias within query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query (below) to insert records into a database. The goal is to insert only new / unique entries in the database. So it will insert the row if the row doesn't already exist in the entire database. I would like to have it evaluate that row against ONLY the rows that have the symbol in the instrumentSymbol, rather than evaluating against every row in the entire database.

I am running into this syntax error which I have pinpointed to be due to the use of an alias in line `SELECT 1 FROM instrumentsHistory WHERE instrumentSymbol = 'ZYME' AS f`

This query works fine if removing the `WHERE instrumentSymbol = {SYMBOL}` conditional, but I need to this to refine the set of records the query compares itself to (thus reducing time to complete task.

I have looked through the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) which leads me to believe there is nothing wrong with this query. Can someone pls point me in the right direction?

The Error:

```
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "AS": syntax error
[SQL: INSERT INTO instrumentsHistory (datetime, instrumentSymbol, observation, observationColName)
                    SELECT t.datetime, t.instrumentSymbol, t.observation, t.observationColName
                    FROM tempTable t
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                        (SELECT 1 FROM instrumentsHistory WHERE instrumentSymbol = 'ZYME' AS f
                         WHERE t.datetime = f.datetime
                         AND t.instrumentSymbol = f.instrumentSymbol
                         AND t.observation = f.observation
                         AND t.observationColName = f.observationColName)]
```

EDIT 1:
Adding complete query...

```
 sql = f"""INSERT INTO instrumentsHistory (datetime, instrumentSymbol, observation, observationColName)
                SELECT t.datetime, t.instrumentSymbol, t.observation, t.observationColName
                FROM tempTable t
                WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                    (SELECT 1 FROM instrumentsHistory WHERE instrumentSymbol = '{symbol}' AS f
                     WHERE t.datetime = f.datetime
                     AND t.instrumentSymbol = f.instrumentSymbol
                     AND t.observation = f.observation
                     AND t.observationColName = f.observationColName)"""
```

Comment: Replace `AS f WHERE` substring in your query text with `AND` substring.

Comment: That wouldn't work because the query is referncing the table `'f` afterwards. For example `WHERE i.datetime = f.datetime` would throw an error

Comment: True. Then `FROM instrumentsHistory WHERE instrumentSymbol = 'ZYME' AS f WHERE` must be replaced with `FROM instrumentsHistory AS f WHERE f.instrumentSymbol = 'ZYME' AND`

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM instrumentsHistory WHERE instrumentSymbol = 'ZYME' AS f
                  WHERE t.datetime = f.datetime
```

has multiple errors. There are two `WHERE` clauses in a row. And `as` is being used in a `WHERE` clause. I am guessing this is a copy-and-past error, but it is unclear what you intend.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, just added complete query in recent edit

Comment: The goal is to insert only new / unique entries in the database. So it will insert the row if the row doesnt already exist in the entire database. I would like to have it evaluate that row against ONLY the rows that have the symbol in the instrumentSymbol, rather than evaluating against every row in the entire database